# Batch file to make folders and move files according to filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm brand new to batch scripting so I appreciate any help. I've seen similar problems here but can't get my move function to work.

I have files with the following format:

```
19013_01-PG-18-1000_NC_IL2RG_Ex2_F_D01.ab1
19013_01-PG-18-1000_NC_IL2RG_Ex2_R_H01.ab1
```

I want to make folders with the following format:

```
01-PG-18-1000_NC_IL2RG_Ex2
```

And then move all the files that have `*01-PG-18-1000_NC*` into that folder name.

Here's what I have so far. It's making the folders the way I want, but I can't get the files to move at all. Tried multiple iterations of the `move` function, but I'm not totally understanding the tokens and how it relates to the files for moving.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir="whatever my directory name is"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=_" %%a IN (
    'dir /b /a-d "*_*-*-*-*_*_*_*.*"'
) DO (  
    MD %%b_%%c_%%d_%%e 2>nul
    MOVE "%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e" "%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e"
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: To format as code, select and press `{}` just above the edit window. Please re-edit in any significant changes you'd made.

Answer (score 1):

Real quickie - and untested

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir="whatever my directory name is"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=_" %%a IN (
    'dir /b /a-d "*_*-*-*-*_*_*_*.*"'
) DO (  
 echo ++%%a++%%b++%%c++%%d++%%e++%%f++
    MD %%b_%%c_%%d_%%e 2>nul
    MOVE "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f" "%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e"
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

You were very close - the `echo` line should show you how the filename is parsed into `%%a`..`%%f`. The parts separated by `++` which is simply a very obvious separator and shows whether there are spaces in any element.

Adding `*` to the token-list means "everything after the highest-mentioned token number". Then reconstruct the filename from the parts - string together starting at `%%a`, re-inserting all the underscores.

This should work also:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir="whatever my directory name is"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f %%q IN (
    'dir /b /a-d "*_*-*-*-*_*_*_*.*"'
) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=_" %%a IN ("%%q") do
    echo ++%%a++%%b++%%c++%%d++%%e++%%f++FROM++%%q++
    MD %%b_%%c_%%d_%%e 2>nul
    MOVE "%%q" "%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e"
 )
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

In this version, `%%q` acquires each filename in turn, then `"%%q"` can be parsed by `for /f` and the original filename remains unmolested in `%%q` ready for use in the `move` statement.

[actually, quite minor] Revision:

```
REM <!-- language: lang-dos -->
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=_" %%a IN (
    'dir /b /a-d "*_*-*-*-*_*_*_*.*"'
) DO IF EXIST "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f" (  
    MD %%b_%%c_%%d_%%e 2>nul
    MOVE "*%%b_%%c*" "%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e"
)
POPD

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t h r e e"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f %%q IN (
    'dir /b /a-d "*_*-*-*-*_*_*_*.*"'
) do IF EXIST "%%q" (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=_" %%a IN ("%%q") DO (
    MD %%b_%%c_%%d_%%e 2>nul
    MOVE "*%%b_%%c*" "%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e"
 )
)
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Yes - misread that you wanted to move **all files containing** - been up gaming all night...

The above batch is in two sections, the first using `%%a`..`%%f` and the second incorporating `%%q`.

The difficulty faced is that `move *[pattern]*` will move all of the files, as desired BUT `for /f...'dir...` builds a list of ALL of the matching files that were originally in the directory.

Once the first filename is processed, those other files containing the `01-PG-18-1000_NC` will have been moved, so you'll get a "no files found" error on the next `01-PG-18-1000_NC` file in the the list `for` has built.

Sure, it's possible to cruft together some mechanism for ensuring that the pattern `01-PG-18-1000_NC` is only processed once, but a simple `if exists` for the full filename returned by `for...%%a...` and rebuilt can be used to gate the `MD/MOVE` commands as the file will no longer exist when the next `01-PG-18-1000_NC` is processed (as it's already been moved). So much easier using the `%%q` method though.

Of course, you could also simply dispose of the error messages instead of installing a gate - but that's probably regarded as being crude.

Also aschipfl's suggestion of adding `delims=` to the `for...%%q...` is quite valid if you have separators like <kbd>Space</kbd> in your filenames (and costs nothing, regardless)

Oh - and I'd missed the `(` in the `do` part in my initial response - always happens when you don't actually test the code, especially when you're tired.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting and all the help, I'm super appreciateive Magoo. Unfortunately both of those options still aren't working. 

It's making the folders how I want %%b_%%c_%%d_%%e
01-PG-18-1300_NC_IL2RG_Ex2

But to move "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f" is it trying to move files with only 19013_01-PG-18-1300_NC_IL2RG_Ex2_F to the folder "01-PG-18-1300_NC_IL2RG_Ex2"? Although it's not doing that either. Should I be using both "_" and "-" as delims? Any more help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Moxy, what `tokens` string are you using? `%%f` is expected to be something like `F_D01.ab1` (referring to your first example file in your question)...

Comment: @Magoo, for the second approach, the outer `for /F` loop should have the option `delims=`, just to account for potential spaces...